# Trying to process json file returned from an API call in NodeJS - error: undefined - why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am receiving a JSON file from an APIcall (see below). Now, I would like to access the different keys of the JSON file to present the various values separately. However, I get an 'undefined' message in the console. Any ideas?

This is the code to call the API and process JSON file:

```html
   const input = req.body.var_1;
    console.log('Request Query:' + JSON.stringify({ "user_input": input}));
    const articles = [];
    const sent = 'test';
    const api_url = '...';
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({"user_input": input}),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }

    const response = await fetch(api_url, options);
    const results = await Promise.all([response.json()]);
    console.log(results);
    data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results))
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.Topic);
```

This is the console output I get:

```html
Request Query:{"user_input":"xgboost"}
[
  {
    Topic: {
      '0': 'random forest , Machine Learning and Wine Quality: Finding a good wine using multiple classifications',
      '1': 'decision tree learning , Gradient Boost for Classification',
      '2': 'feature selection , Understanding Multilabel Text Classification and the related process',
      '3': 'decision tree learning , Gradient Boost for Regression',
      '4': '<strong class="markup--strong markup--h3-strong">Understanding AdaBoost</strong> , Anyone starting to learn Boosting technique should start first with AdaBoost or…'
    },
    'URL/PDF': {
      '0': 'https://dev.to//leading-edje/machine-learning-and-wine-quality-finding-a-good-wine-using-multiple-classifications-4kho',
      '1': 'https://dev.to//xsabzal/gradient-boost-for-classification-2f15',
      '2': 'https://dev.to//botreetechnologies/understanding-multilabel-text-classification-and-the-related-process-n66',
      '3': 'https://dev.to//xsabzal/gradient-boost-for-regression-1e42',
      '4': 'https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-adaboost-2f94f22d5bfe'
    },
    Doc_Type: {
      '0': 'article',
      '1': 'article',
      '2': 'article',
      '3': 'article',
      '4': 'article'
    }
  }
]
[
  {
    Topic: {
      '0': 'random forest , Machine Learning and Wine Quality: Finding a good wine using multiple classifications',
      '1': 'decision tree learning , Gradient Boost for Classification',
      '2': 'feature selection , Understanding Multilabel Text Classification and the related process',
      '3': 'decision tree learning , Gradient Boost for Regression',
      '4': '<strong class="markup--strong markup--h3-strong">Understanding AdaBoost</strong> , Anyone starting to learn Boosting technique should start first with AdaBoost or…'
    },
    'URL/PDF': {
      '0': 'https://dev.to//leading-edje/machine-learning-and-wine-quality-finding-a-good-wine-using-multiple-classifications-4kho',
      '1': 'https://dev.to//xsabzal/gradient-boost-for-classification-2f15',
      '2': 'https://dev.to//botreetechnologies/understanding-multilabel-text-classification-and-the-related-process-n66',
      '3': 'https://dev.to//xsabzal/gradient-boost-for-regression-1e42',
      '4': 'https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-adaboost-2f94f22d5bfe'
    },
    Doc_Type: {
      '0': 'article',
      '1': 'article',
      '2': 'article',
      '3': 'article',
      '4': 'article'
    }
  }
]
undefined
```

Happy for any help, thx

Comment: I don't understand this line `await Promise.all([response.json()])`. It should probably be `await response.json();`. For some reason you're wrapping it in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Note the `[ ]` in the output - `results` (or `data`, for that matter) is an *array*, so the `Topic` would be `results[0].Topic` (the array itself doesn't have a property `Topic`, only its element has one, hence the `undefined` result).

**But:** It shouldn't even be an array in the first place, it only is one because you make it one here:

```js
const results = await Promise.all([response.json()]);
```

`Promise.all` will wait for an array of promises and return an array of their resolved values. You provide an array with one promise, so you will get back *an array with one value*, instead of getting only the value itself.

There is no point in using `Promise.all` with just one promise though, so you can get rid of that part and thereby also get rid of the array:

```js
const results = await response.json()
console.log(results.Topic)
```

(As you can see, the whole `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` shenanigans are superfluous as well.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the Object nested in an array so you have to access the first item in the array with `data[0].Topic`.